# How high is too high for hydrogen to rise?

Tags: density, buoyancy, fluid-statics

At which point does hydrogen stop rising even if a balloon would never pop? If hydrogen is the lightest gas would not all of it rise making the highest part of the atmosphere?

It is not homework.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it shows insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @JohnRennie, I agree.

Comment: @Muze Go research buoyancy and density, two very important concepts for floating balloons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ballon will stop rising when the net force on it becomes zero, which means that the buoyancy cancels the ballon's weight (gravitational force acting on it). This will happen when the density of the gas filling the ballon equals the density of the surrounding air.

Comment: This is a very "hand-wavy" answer, and is probably incorrect.

Comment: It was a hand wavy question. In fact, I'm waving my hands right now! :)

Comment: @DavidWhite what is your answer?

Comment: The surrounding air density must be greater than the density of the hydrogen in the balloon, because the associated buoyant force must support the weight of the hydrogen AND the weight of the balloon.  In addition, the solar wind would heat any "loose" hydrogen to the point where it would escape the earth due to hydrogen molecules' high velocity, so the hydrogen in the balloon cannot exist with high atmosphere "air" that has the same density, because this condition requires the balloon to be floating in hydrogen.

Comment: Your answer was also hand wavish, except for the fact that you considered solar winds (?). I also disagree with your last sentence: the difference in the materials does not prevent anything from floating. A ball floats in water and it's not made of water. Also, when I said "weight", I was referring to the whole ballon... And I think you're being too specific, maybe. In a word: we're both waving out hands, but it looks like you're waving them faster!

Comment: I don't know if I'm waving my hands faster or not, but I DO know that the OP's question needs a lot more detail before it can be adequately answered.

Comment: Let's leave that for the OP to decide :) I hope someone (you?) answer it thoroughly with Newton's second law, including the balloon's mass and some particle showers from the solar winds. I'll be your first up vote! ;)

Comment: My point is that the density of the surrounding air must be greater than the density of the hydrogen in the balloon in order to support it.  I seriously doubt that you can create a situation where the surrounding "air" density is equal to the density of the hydrogen in the balloon.